# How to install firefox from snap, when my /tmp is symlinked to another place?

Tags: permissions, firefox, snap, apparmor

Upgraded my desktop to ubuntu jammy, and this is forcing me to use firefox from snaps.

The problem - `snap install firefox` fails with:

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run configure hook of "firefox" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot create temporary directory for the root file system: Permission denied)
```

Checked with strace, and it seems that the problem was:

```
10:56:07.401761 mkdir("/tmp/snap.rootfs_b4V7qn", 0700) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied) <0.000031>
```

The problem, in my case, is that /tmp is symlinked to another place:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 sty  3 14:50 /tmp -> /mnt/storage/tmp//
```

Of course there are 777 privileges to it:

```
drwxrwxrwt 81 root root 20480 May  6 12:53 /mnt/storage/tmp
```

, but clearly something (apparmor?) is causing problems.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than symlinking, "mount --bind" your `/tmp` to the new location. A mount --bind relocates a directory at a deeper level than symbolic links do, and such binds are "seen" by snap.

To mount --bind your `/tmp` file automatically during startup, add following line to your `/etc/fstab` configuration file:

```
/mnt/storage/tmp /tmp none bind
```

After this, `/tmp` appears as a normal directory `/tmp` rather than a symbolic link, and accordingly the Firefox snap version will install without error.

Comment: This did in fact solve this problem. But it leads to question. Is there any way, from running system, that I can figure out where the /tmp is mounted from? Assuming /etc/fstab is not having it.
Simple `mount` just shows: `/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-storage on /tmp type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,discard,errors=remount-ro)` and doesn't say that it's /tmp dir on this device...